# Bash exit code of the test part should not be 0

Tags: bash

Why is this bash script returning an exit code of 0?

```
$ if [ $NonExistent != "something" ]; then echo good; fi; echo $?
-bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
0
```

I've tried putting the script in a file and adding

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

but it still returns 0. Assuming I can't modify this script and can only invoke it, is there a way I could know that the script failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning 0 because

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

> `if`
>
> [...]
>
> The return status is the exit status of the last command executed, or **zero if no condition tested true**.

As for knowing that the script failed: What exactly do you mean by "failed"? It runs through successfully.

You could test whether the output starts with `good` if you want to know whether the condition was true or not.

Comment: This makes so much sense! I should have thought that 'if' was actually evaluating the return code of the test expression. Either the expression fails because of a bad syntax or because it evaluates to false, 'if' executes successfully hence the 0 exit code.