# Can I make bad [ syntax in a bash if statement cause the shell to exit with an error?

Tags: bash, if-statement, exit-code

Consider the following `bash` code:

```bash
if [ "$a" = "foo"]
then
  echo "TRUE"
fi
echo $?
```

we get:

```bash
bash: [: missing `]'
0
```

So basically, the test in the if fails due to a typo (no space between `"foo"` and `]`), but the exit code of the whole `if` is still `0` aka. success.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788073/bash-exit-code-of-the-test-part-should-not-be-0) explains why the exit code is `0` (we get the exit code of `if` which is `0` because nothing was `true`).

So far so good, but this behavior is extremely dangerous as it can lead to silent errors. Is there a way to rewrite the condition, or change any `bash` settings, such that typos like these trigger a non-zero exit of the script / `ìf`?

Comment: I don't think so. `[` isn't part of the `if` syntax, it's just a command that you're running as the test.

Comment: `if` can't tell the difference between `[` failing because of a syntax error or because the condition is false.

Comment: Yes, this is clear from the other answer. The question is if we can make `bash` recognize syntax errors as errors and abort with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @Seriously, but it **isn't** a syntax error: it's perfectly fine bash syntax. `[` has its own syntax distinct from that of bash -- and while _in practice_ bash provides its own implementation of `[` command, that's just a performance optimization; if `/usr/bin/[` and `[` behaved differently at the language level, then you'd have reinvented `[[`.

Comment: As a real-world practical solution that doesn't require people to rearchitect things that have decades of backwards-compatibility requirements (not to mention the need for compliance with literal standards-body-ratified standards) solidifying their current design: Use a text editor with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) support built in. Personally, I use [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/) with [bash-language-server](https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server), so when I write code with the bug at hand, my editor flags it immediately.

Comment: (if you want bash to be able to distinguish between a false test result and bad test syntax, maybe you **should** stop using `[` and switch to exclusively using `[[` regardless; `[[` isn't standardized, so bash can change its behavior without breaking standards / backwards compatibility / etc, and bad `[[` syntax _is_ already recognized as bad bash syntax; the behavior of `[` isn't quite literally set in stone, but it _is_ tightly constrained in a way that makes "hey, here's this good idea I just had!" changes generally implausible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to rewrite the condition: **Don't use `[`**.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [[ "$a" = "foo"]]
then
  echo "TRUE"
fi
echo "REACHED"
```

properly results in:

```
yourscript: line 1: syntax error in conditional expression
```

You can see this tested at https://ideone.com/ZH1Znb

---

Alternately, you can check the exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# using legacy ksh syntax because some versions of bash are picky
# about function names with POSIX-y syntax; in new bash, though,
# this also works with `[() {` as the first line.
function [ {
  builtin [ "$@" || {
    rc=$?
    case $rc in
      0|1) return $?;;
      *) echo "ERROR: Bad test syntax" >&2; exit "$rc";;
    esac
  }
}

if [ "$a" = foo]
then
  echo "TRUE"
fi
echo "REACHED"
```

but this is obviously a horrid abomination.

---

Note that while the above examples use `set -e`, this feature has [serious pitfalls, and I strongly advise against its use](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Answer (score 1):

`if` doesn't distinguish between different reasons for `[` failing. However, it sets different exit status depending on whether the condition failed or there was an other error. The exit status will be `1` when the condition fails, errors will be greater than 1.

So you could check `$?` explicitly to distinguish:

```
[ "$a" = "foo"] 2>/dev/null
case $? in
    0) echo "TRUE" ;;
    1) ;;
    *) (exit 1) ;;
esac
echo $? # prints 1
```

Comment: I've redirected the output to `/dev/null` to suppress that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually bad syntax of the `if` statement, but of the `[` command. That command fails due to not finding the `]` closing argument.

So what you have here is equivalent to:

```
if false; then
  echo "TRUE"
fi
```

The failed termination status of the tested command is not propagated to `if`.

You just need an `else`:

```
if command_that_fails_for_any_reason ; then
   echo "okay"
else
   false 
fi
```

That `false` will now cause the command to have a failed termination status, so the script will bail in `set -e` mode.

If the failed status of the test command propagated to `if`, that would meant that `if` could not be to prevent termination of a script in `set -e` mode.

In the following example, the script would die if `checked_command` failed, in spite of script reacting to its termination status.

```
set -e
unchecked_command #  this will terminate the script if it fails

if checked_command ; then   # the script is testing this one
  : ...
fi
```

We can argue that the error handling is incomplete here because the `if` is testing only for the successful case.  Nevertheless, according to the design of the shell language, and the `set -e` feature, if the script tests the termination status, it's considered to have taken on the full responsibility for it.

Having the script bail would be annoying in situations like:

```
if grep -s pattern /some/file ; then
   : # react to pattern being found in file
fi
```